# Jackson Polymorphism and @JsonTypeInfo usage

Tags: jackson

Based on the following JSON:

```
{"items": [
    {
      "post_id": 17168289,
      "count": 190
    }
]}
```

And:

```
{"items": [
    {
      "tag_id": 17168289,
      "count": 190
    }
]}
```

I want to create a Tag object and a Post object that both extend an Item object.

How can I use the `@JsonTypeInfo`  annotation to pick up the name of the  *_id field so Jackson creates the correct object?

Here's where I am so far:

```
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Post.class, name="post_id")
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Tag.class, name="tag_id")

})
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)  
public class Item {

   public int count;

}
```